# Converting multiple lists number into one list

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, numpy, arraylist

1. Why I get this bracket '[]' when I try to generate a number?
2. How to convert this array list into a standard list, e.g. [1124, 2209, ….]
   [data manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk3Nf.png)

Comment: You should change `size` arg like this `np.random.normal(10, 4, size = 19)` to avoid this problem. Additionally, it would be better if you posted a piece of code here not a screenshot :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot Marsha. Okey for further issue I"ll load the code rather than the screenshot